# What fundamental force does a pressure cooker operate on?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, forces, pressure

As a child, I wondered which fundamental force a pressure cooker used. My guess right now is electromagnetism as the others seem to be very unlikely. Which fundamental force does it use and how? For example, friction depends on the EM force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the strong and weak force are restricted (mostly) to act within a nucleus and gravity is much too weak in a regular sized pressure cooker, the only fundamental force that is left is electromagnetism.

It is basically the atoms or molecules in the cooker bouncing off each other, where the repulsion comes from the EM force, because the shell electrons repell each other.

Comment: You could say that the water cooker itself is being held together by the weak and strong forces.

Comment: @gertian well, the cores of the atoms of the water cooker, but not the material itself. But this is also true for the atoms making up the gas. The material making up the cooker is also held together by EM forces.

Comment: I know I was just thinking a bit out of the box :)